# Exception + Apache derby + ERROR XSDB0: Unexpected exception on in-memory page Page(89,Container(0, 560)) Apache derby java

Tags: java, derby

I am using Eclipselink on java and a have this exception when i trying to open a derby database:

```
ERROR XSDB0: Unexpected exception on in-memory page Page(89,Container(0, 560))

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/home/vmonsanto/NetBeansProjects/database/exercise' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, see the next exception for details.
Error Code: 40000
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/home/vmonsanto/NetBeansProjects/database/exercise' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, see the next exception for details.
Error Code: 40000
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at net.advance.mindbodyhandnet.ui.ParametrosForm.initComponents(ParametrosForm.java:39)
    at net.advance.mindbodyhandnet.ui.ParametrosForm.<init>(ParametrosForm.java:23)
    at net.advance.mindbodyhandnet.ui.ParametrosForm$1.run(ParametrosForm.java:364)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/home/vmonsanto/NetBeansProjects/database/exercise' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, see the next exception for details.
Error Code: 40000
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/home/vmonsanto/NetBeansProjects/database/exercise' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database '/home/vmonsanto/NetBeansProjects/database/exercise' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDFI: Error encountered while trying to write data to disk during database recovery.  Check that the database disk is not full. If it is then delete unnecessary files, and retry connecting to the database.  It is also possible that the file system is read only, or the disk has failed, or some other problem with the media.  System encountered error while processing page Page(89,Container(0, 560)).
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.reCreatePageForRedoRecovery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseContainerHandle.reCreatePageForRedoRecovery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.InitPageOperation.getPageForRedoRecovery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.PageBasicOperation.findpage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.PageBasicOperation.needsRedo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.FileLogger.redo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.recover(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: ERROR XSLAA: The store has been marked for shutdown by an earlier exception.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.CachedPage.writePage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.CachedPage.createIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.create(Unknown Source)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB0: Unexpected exception on in-memory page Page(89,Container(0, 560))
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.StoredPage.initSlotTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.StoredPage.initFromData(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.CachedPage.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.getAnyPage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseContainer.getAnyPage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseContainerHandle.getAnyPage(Unknown Source)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: Start by gathering the full exception data: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem deleting log2.dat and log.dat from log directory, but is very important make a database backup before do this, y lose some data but work for me.